# Entries not cited in the text not printed in the References page

Tags: bibliographies, citing

How do I include a reference that has not been mentioned in the text?

With the settings below, only the sources cited by `\cite{stuff}` are printed in the references page.

`\nocite` and `\nocite{*}` doesn't work with abntex2 class.

If possible, i would like a solution that keep settings of abntex2cite package.

```
\documentclass[
               12pt,
               a4paper,
               openright,
               %twoside,
               oneside,             
               dvipsnames,
               chapter=TITLE,       
               section=TITLE,       
               english,
               brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[
                    alf,
                    abnt-emphasize=bf,
                    bibjustif,
                    recuo=0cm,
                    abnt-etal-cite=4,
                    abnt-etal-text=it]{abntex2cite} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

[]'s

Ulysses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\nocite` worked when I tried it, this has one visible `\cite` and two references in the list at the end.

(Please always provide complete documents, not just fragments)

[image]

```
\documentclass[
               12pt,
               a4paper,
               openright,
               %twoside,
               oneside,             
               dvipsnames,
               chapter=TITLE,       
               section=TITLE,       
               english,
               brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[
                    alf,
                    abnt-emphasize=bf,
                    bibjustif,
                    recuo=0cm,
                    abnt-etal-cite=4,
                    abnt-etal-text=it]{abntex2cite} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

xxx\cite{inbook-full}

xxx\nocite{article-full}

\bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Carlisle. I can't figure what was going on. It's ok now.